# place text next to thumbnail instead of center

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Currently, my username text appears in the center of the view. I want to change it such that it appears on the exact right of the thumbnail. If I remove the `alignItems: 'center',` from the item, it disturbs the whole style. How else can I fix this?

```
import { StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text, Button, Thumbnail } from 'native-base';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

 return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Thumbnail
          style={styles.thumbnail}
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/avatars-xmas-giveaway/128/afro_woman_female_person-512.png',
          }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.userName}>USER NAME</Text>
      </View>
      <Button
        rounded
        style={styles.deleteButton}>
        <Icon name="trash-o" size={moderateScale(20)} color="black" />
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    borderRadius: moderateScale(20),
    padding: moderateScale(20),
    marginVertical: moderateScale(8),
    marginHorizontal: 16,
    height: moderateScale(70),
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  thumbnail: {
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  nameContainer: {
    //flex: 1,
    // alignItems: 'center',
    // textAlign: 'center',
  },
  userName: {
    paddingRight: moderateScale(55),
    paddingLeft: moderateScale(20),
    //textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '900'
  },
  deleteButton: {
    backgroundColor: '#31C283',
    width: moderateScale(45),
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  horizontalLine: {
    marginTop: moderateScale(30),
    width: '87%',
    height: moderateScale(1),
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
});
```

I tried creating a snack expo but I am unable to use native base in it.

[image]

Comment: If you can create a reproducible example in e.g. CodeSandbox. It would be more convenient for people to help you.

Comment: You need to wrap thumbnail and the text in one view and the right button in other view.

Comment: This can be achieved using `flex`

Comment: @DanielCheung unable to install native base in snack expo

Comment: where exactly should I use flex? @Awais

Comment: @Jnl here is and exapmple you justt ned to make 1 and 2 div inside one parent like saachi said in above commnet https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-space-between-the-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added unwanted padding, Change the styles like below and it will place the text next to the Thumbnail.

```
  nameContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  userName: {
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: '900'
  },
```